# Restart Timer after countdown in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, countdown, antd

I'm working on a simple counter that popup a modal then close again after the timer in modal reach zero, My problem is I don't know how to restart again the first counter.

Hope you understand me.

Thanks.

[SAMPLE CODE](https://codesandbox.io/s/8168174w82)

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(this.countDown, 1000);
    this.setState({ seconds: this.props.time });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let timeLeftVar = this.secondsToTime(this.state.seconds);
    this.setState({ time: timeLeftVar });
  }
  countDown() {
    // Remove one second, set state so a re-render happens.
    let seconds = this.state.seconds - 1;
    this.setState({
      time: this.secondsToTime(seconds),
      seconds: seconds
    });

    // Check if we're at zero.
    if (seconds === 0) {
      clearInterval(this.timer);
      this.setState({
        visible: true
      });
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({ currentCount: this.state.currentCount - 1 });
        if (this.state.currentCount === 0) {
          clearInterval(this.interval);
          this.setState({ visible: false });
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

take the content of componentWillMount out and put it in a different function:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.foo();
  }

  foo() {
    this.timer = setInterval(this.countDown, 1000);
    this.setState({ seconds: this.props.time });
  }
```

then you must call this.foo() when interval gets to 0:

```
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.setState({ currentCount: this.state.currentCount - 1 });
    if (this.state.currentCount === 0) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      this.setState({ visible: false });
      this.foo();
    }
  }, 1000);
```